# What were the initial conditions in "Quantum Walk on a Line with Two Entangled Particles"?

Tags: quantum-entanglement

I could use some help understanding the initial conditions described in

Omar, Yasser & Paunkovic, N. & Sheridan, L. & Bose, Somesuvra. (2004). Quantum Walk on a Line with Two Entangled Particles. Physical Review A. 74. 10.1103/PHYSREVA.74.042304.

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2194149_Quantum_Walk_on_a_Line_with_Two_Entangled_Particles

This is Figure 2:

> [image: Omar 2004 Fig. 2]

Figure 2a is for uncorrelated particles.
Figures 2b and 2c are entangled cases.  This contains more of the description/explanation of Figure 2:

> [image: Omar 2004 Explanation of Fig 2]

What is meant by the "+" case and the "-" case?  Is it describing entanglement that is correlated and anti-correlated or is the "+" and "-" something else altogether?